# How do I found out which node an Erlang process (PID) is running on?

Tags: erlang, distribution, pid, erlang-otp

Given that I can send PIDs from a process to an other, even across nodes, if I receive a Pid from a process within a different process (possibly on a different node) how do I find out which node the PID in question runs in/on?

`erlang:process_info(Pid)` does not seem to have that information in it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 18):

[`erlang:node/1`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#node-1)

> node(Arg) -> Node
>
> Returns the node where Arg is located. Arg can be a pid, a reference, or a port. If the local node is not alive, nonode@nohost is returned.