# How to convert remote pid to node name?

Tags: erlang

When deciding one client parameter structure to one `OTP` gen_server, is it necessary to insert both `Pid` and `Node name` into the parameter structure?

Given one remote `pid`, is it possible to convert `pid` to `node name`? I mean full node name, like `"emacs@yus-iMac.local".`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I found out which node an erlang process is running on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7083980/how-do-i-found-out-which-node-an-erlang-process-is-running-on)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Can someone explain the structure of a Pid in Erlang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/243363/can-someone-explain-the-structure-of-a-pid-in-erlang)

[How do I found out which node an erlang process is running on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7083980/how-do-i-found-out-which-node-an-erlang-process-is-running-on)

Comment: On the otp gen_server side, if just receiving remote pid, the server doesn't know the node name. In addition, for writing load balance between nodes, erlang:nodes() return a group of nodes' name, so I need to convert pid to node name.

Comment: erlang:node (Pid) returns atom that is node name.

Answer (score 5):

Calling `node(Pid)` will return the name of the node on which `Pid` resides.